# idlj-maven-plugin and package translation

Tags: java, maven, corba, idl

I am trying to include a Corba .idl file in a Maven project with [idlj-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/idlj-maven-plugin/usage.html). The .idl file specifies a certain module, say

```
module Tester
{
  interface Test {
    void sayHello();
  }
}
```

and I would like the generated classes to belong in the package `com.mycompany.tester`. I have tried using

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>idlj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <debug>true</debug>
            <compiler>jacorb</compiler>
            <sourceDirectory>../../idl</sourceDirectory>
            <source>
                <packageTranslations>
                    <packageTranslation>
                        <type>Tester</type>
                        <package>com.mycompany.tester</package>
                    </packageTranslation>
                </packageTranslations>
            </source>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

but it seems to have absolutely no effect. I also tried to use `idlj` as `<compiler>`, or to use

```
                <additionalArguments>
                    <additionalArgument>
                        -i2jpackage Tester:com.mycompany.tester
                    </additionalArgument>
                </additionalArguments>
```

but nothing seems to have any effect.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to make everything work in this way:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>idlj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <debug>true</debug>
            <compiler>jacorb</compiler>
            <sourceDirectory>../../idl</sourceDirectory>
            <sources>
                <source>
                    <additionalArguments>
                        <list>-i2jpackage</list>
                        <list>Tester:com.mycompany.tester</list>
                    </additionalArguments>
                </source>
            </sources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

When using `<compiler>idlj</compiler>` I used instead, for `<additionalArguments>`:

```
<additionalArguments>
    <list>-pkgTranslate</list>
    <list>Tester</list>
    <list>com.mycompany.tester</list>
</additionalArguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use command idlj

```
====  your tester.idl  ====

module tester
{
    interface Test {
        void sayHello();
    }
}

===========================
```

you can use the idlj with options `-pkgPrefix` to generate java files to a certain package, just as following

```
idlj -pkgPrefix tester com.mycompany -fall tester.idl
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the examples in the idlj-maven-plugin usage page suggest otherwise, you have to wrap the source options in a sources element:

```
<configuration>
    <compiler>jacorb</compiler>
    <sources>
        <source>
            <packagePrefix>com.acme</packagePrefix>
        </source>
    </sources>
</configuration>
```